# Set Lists elements in proper / effective way in Java

Tags: java, android, list

I am programming in Java some Android project. I want to set 0 into all elements from List

```
int j = 0;
for(@SuppressWarnings("unused") Integer integ : listItemsNum) {
   listItemsNum.set(j, 0);
   j++;
}
```

How to make it more effective?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Collections.fill(List<? super T> list, T object)` method. More on this: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html

Sample:

```
Collections.fill(yourList, Integer.valueOf(0))
```

Comment: It seems to be best way. I have to learn more about Collections. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you could use an array of int instead. The elements of such an array are automatically initialized with value 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < listItemsNum; i++ ) {
      listItemsNum.set( i, 0 );
    }
```